# Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: asp.net

I am facing an error on the web page that I am working on. The problem is when I try to open up the web page: www.ice-tech.com It loads fine, but when you try to refresh it, it crashes.

You can see the error itself on-line. Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe you should post some code and an actual traceback instead.  This question is not likely to be helpful to anyone in the future if understanding it depends on a transient problem in an external web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following code failing:

```
Line 36:         If ConnectCount = 0 Then
Line 37:             ' Close the Connection
Line 38:             Conn.Close()
Line 39:             Conn = Nothing
Line 40:         End If
```

Looks like you are closing a connection that has already been closed. Check the Conncetion.State before closing it (again).

For more information see [ConnectionState Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate.aspx).

Possible solution:

```
If ConnectCount = 0 And Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open Then
    ' Close the Connection
    Conn.Close()
    Conn = Nothing
End If
```